# Trigger automation test from Octopus

Tags: c#, nuget, specflow, octopus-deploy, octopus

Problem : 
We have set of UI automated tests which I want to trigger on different environment manually from Octopus UI.

Environment : .Net project, TFS integrated with Octopus

Currently, based on each check-in automation tests are triggered in CI environment and later is promoted to Test and Integration. On each environment a different set of automation suites are triggered.

I am looking for a solution, so that I can trigger multiple automation regression suite manually based on requirement of any of the environment (CI, Test and UAT)

Need help / suggestions how I can make this work.

We are following process as mentioned in this thread : [Octopus and Continuous Integration - What's the best practice around when a release should be created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902891/octopus-and-continuous-integration-whats-the-best-practice-around-when-a-rele#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add App.Config for each environment so your Env becomes parameter.

For example: App.Dev.Config will run against dev environment.

You can use MSBuild to build your solution and you will need to pass your buildConfiguration="Dev". Then you can execute that dll with vstest.console.exe.

You can write PowerShell script that does that. You can trigger this test from anywhere Octapus or CI.

Hope this helps.